# Pandoc not exporting bibliography, images and nested sections

Tags: graphics, bibliographies, conversion, pandoc

I'm a new Pandoc user, primarily for converting `.tex` files in `.odt` format.

The following command:

```
pandoc -f latex -t odt -o prova.odt roottoptesi.tex
```

Works well apart for the fact that it can't find images, as from the pandoc output:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `evolution.jpg', skipping...
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `ZoneUniversita.png', skipping...
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `dimensioniuniversita.png', skipping...
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `popolazionestudentesca.png', skipping...
```

The second problem is that I don't get the bibliography printed in the output file. I don't get any error message for this.

Third problem is I can't include `.tex` files beyond one level of nesting.

Below is the LaTeX code to be converted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{toptesi}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {immagini/} }
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\input{intro.tex}
[...]
\input{cap5.tex}

\bibliography{biblioprova}
\end{document}
```

I guess that the problem with images is lying in

```
  \graphicspath{ {immagini/} }
```

but I'm not quite sure.

`cap5.tex` is formed by four different subsections I'd rather keep in separate files, and I can't have them printed in the final .odt file. The structure of the chapter is the following:

```
\chapter{Focus comparativo} \label{Cap5}
\input{sottosez5.1}
\input{sottosez5.2}
\input{sottosez5.3}
\input{sottosez5.4}
```

I could easily merge them together, but maybe I can solve this within Pandoc.

As for the bibliography, I'm clueless about the causes.

Comment: According to [a recent comment](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/736) (scroll to the end of the page), the `\graphicspath` feature should be fixed soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the bug was reported and listed in the software tracklist